# Add and remove classes to random div with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to set up a row of circles that randomly change classes at a certain interval, but I can't figure out how to take what I have below and make it so that each .circle shifts to a different random class. Currently the code below will change all .circle divs to the same random class.

```
var classes = [
"cls-1",
"cls-2",
"cls-3",
"cls-4"
];
var $div = $(".circle");
setInterval(function() {
$.each(classes, function(i, c) {
    if ($div.hasClass(c)) {
        var j = Math.floor ( Math.random() * classes.length );
        $div.removeClass(c).addClass(classes[j]);
        return false;
    }
});
}, 1000);
```

This is probably something simple that I'm overlooking, but I'm pretty new to javascript and would appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In setInterval, you can call the function which first removes all the classes from the `classes` array from the divs, then adds a random class from the same array to it.

```js
var classes = [
    "cls-1",
    "cls-2",
    "cls-3",
    "cls-4"
    ];
    var $div = $(".circle");
    setInterval(function() {
     $div.each(function(index){
      $(this).removeClass( classes.join(" ") );
      $(this).addClass( classes[ Math.floor( Math.random() * classes.length ) ] );
     });//each
    }, 1000); //setInterval

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```css
.circle
{
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 60px;
}

.circle.cls-1{ background-color: red; }
.circle.cls-2{ background-color: green; }
.circle.cls-3{ background-color: blue; }
.circle.cls-4{ background-color: black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks so much!